# Value is not initialized into the variable in c

Tags: c, scope, pass-by-value, function-declaration

Here is the program I have made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Put variables here
    int space = 0;
    int num_of_rows = 0;
    int p = 1;
    int t = 0;
    char alphabet[100] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    get_and_validate_user_input(num_of_rows);
    printf(" The number of rows are : %d", num_of_rows);
}

void get_and_validate_user_input(int num_of_rows)
{
    //Input validation
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of rows : ");
        //Getting the input from the user
        scanf("%d", &num_of_rows);

        if (num_of_rows <= 0)
        {
            printf("Negative numbers are not allowed here \n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Input:
Enter the number of rows: 5

Expected Ouput:
The number of rows is: 5

But from my code output shows wrong. It shows: The number of rows is: 0

Now my question is: What's wrong I have been made in my program? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you read your compiler warnings?

Comment: Please format your code in some sane way. Expecting others to read this messy code is plain rude. Then study how functions and parameter passing work.

Comment: @Ashiful Islam Prince You initialized the variable with zero int num_of_rows=0;. So what you are doing is waht you are getting.:) The function deals with a copy of the value of the variable. So changing of the copy does not influence on the original variable.

Comment: Yes, But I don't understand what It says. It says that the implicit declaration of the function and conflicting types of this function. @klutt

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince The function should be declared before its usage for example before main.

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince And the value of the parameter is not used within the function.

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince When you post a question, you should include the exact warning and error message. Furthermore, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Function arguments are *pass by value*, which means the value is copied into the argument variable. Modifying a copy won't change the original. Please do some research about *emulate pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Ok, I am going to research about this. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince I use that way in my answer, read it. I encourage also to take care when you read a value, look at *scanf* return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not see in the point of the call

```
get_and_validate_user_input(num_of_rows);
```

how the function `get_and_validate_user_input` is declared. So the compiler issue a message. It expects that the function by default has the return type `int` but when it encountered the function definition it sees that the return type is `void`.

Place the function declaration before main.

The value of the passed parameter is not used in the function

```
void get_and_validate_user_input(int num_of_rows){
    //...
    //Getting the input from the user
    scanf("%d",&num_of_rows);
    //...
```

The function parameter num_of_rows is a local variable of the function that is initialized by the value of the passed argument. So changing the local variable does not influence on the original argument.

You could declare and define the function like

```
int get_and_validate_user_input( void )
{
    int num_of_rows = 0;

    //Input validation
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of rows : ");
        //Getting the input from the user
        scanf("%d", &num_of_rows);

        if (num_of_rows <= 0)
        {
            printf("Negative numbers are not allowed here \n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return num_of_rows;
}
```

And call it in main like

```
num_of_rows = get_and_validate_user_input();
```

Comment: I got it sir where I made wrong. Thank you. @Vlad from Moscow

Answer (score 1):

your problem is *get_and_validate_user_input* modifies the *local* variable *num_of_rows* => the value stay 0 in *main*

if you want to have *num_of_rows* modified also out of *get_and_validate_user_input* give it  by address rather than by value, example (unused variable commented, modify check in *get_and_validate_user_input* to be compatible with message) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_and_validate_user_input(int * num_of_rows);

int 
main(void){
  //Put variables here
  //int space=0;
  int num_of_rows=0;
  //int p=1;
  //int t=0;
  //char alphabet[100]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
  
  get_and_validate_user_input(&num_of_rows);
  printf(" The number of rows is : %d\n",num_of_rows);
  return 0;
 }

void get_and_validate_user_input(int * num_of_rows){
  //Input validation
  while(1){
    printf("Enter the number of rows : ");
    //Getting the input from the user
    if (scanf("%d",num_of_rows) != 1) {
      int c;

      puts("Invalid input");
      // invalid input, bypass all the line
      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
          puts("EOF, abort");
          exit(-1);
        }
      }
    }
    else if(*num_of_rows < 0){ // 0 seems allowed, else update message
      printf("Negative numbers are not allowed here \n");
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Enter the number of rows : 12
 The number of rows is : 12
/tmp % ./a.out
Enter the number of rows : aze
Invalid input
Enter the number of rows : -2
Negative numbers are not allowed here 
Enter the number of rows : 12
 The number of rows is : 12
/tmp %
```